# Facebook social plugin doesn't working on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer

I'm new on facebook developer and i have created a page tab which contains a login using facebook php sdk (works on all browsers), and like button + feed dialog using facebook javascript sdk (works on all browsers -chrome, FF, safari- except IE).

After 4h of research and tests, I have created a simple page test.html which displays a like button. When I opened it directly outside facebook it worked on all browsers except IE. The IE console shows no error message in this page test.

I use IE 11 but when i emulated IE11- the problem is still here.
Note 1 : in the code, i call window.fbAsyncInit and IE doesn't show the alert.
Note 2 : the domain is in https

The entire code of the page test.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="fr" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<a href="test.html">test</a><br /> <!-- just shortcut to reload -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      alert(1);       // IE only doesn't shwo this alert
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX',  // my api ID
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.2',
          cookie     : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js";
     //js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/debug.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/naintrepides" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were online discussions that IE doesn't support the MIME type value of "application/javascript". I was hoping that at this time and age it should especially with the recent version of IE you are using.

Try changing it to:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

instead.